# Accounts.changePassword doesn't work in Method

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts, meteor-methods

I'm working on a Meteor app, and I want to move a call to `Accounts.changePassword` from the client to a method. However, when I try to run the method, I get this server error :

> Exception while invoking method 'setPersonalPassword' TypeError:
> Object [object Object] has no method 'changePassword'

This is the offending code:

```
'setPersonalPassword': function(oldPassword, newPassword){
    Accounts.changePassword(oldPassword, newPassword);
},
```

However, this code works fine on the client:

```
'submit form': function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var oldPassword = event.target.oldPassword.value;
    var newPassword = event.target.newPassword.value;
    Accounts.changePassword(oldPassword, newPassword)
}
```

I'm particularly confused because I've successfully used both `Accounts.createUser()` and `Accounts.setPassword()` in other methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the server you should use `Accounts.setPassword` which you can use with the current `userId` from the method invocation:

```js
Meteor.methods({
  'setPersonalPassword': function (newPassword){
    const userId = this.userId
    Accounts.changePassword(userId, newPassword)
  }
},
```

See: https://docs.meteor.com/api/passwords.html#Accounts-setPassword

Comment: I was about to ask why that is, but I just noticed that in the upper right-hand corner of the documentation for each function says either Server, Client, or Anywhere. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Does anyone know why Meteor has functions for interacting with server-side stuff that only work on the client? It seems kind of contrary to the paradigm of methods. I could think of them like Methods that you call from the client, but then why do some of them work on the server?

Comment: They abstract the work for you. You can check their source that is linked in the docs. There are also methods called but they made it easier to work with using these functions.